# How Can I Allow Custom Values With Bootstrap Tags Input and typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to use the [Bootstrap Tags Input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) v.0.5.0 with [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) v.0.11.1 and Bootstrap v3.3.5. It is working for me with the exception that I am unable to enter tags that do not exist in my typeahead source array. What do I need to change in order to allow input of items that don't exist in my source array?

Here's my sample html:

```
<input type="text" id="dailyTagsInput" name="dailyTagsInput" class="form-control">
```

Here's my sample js:

```
    $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];

$scope.statesSource = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: $scope.states
});

$('#dailyTagsInput').tagsinput({
  maxChars: 50,
  maxTags: 10,
  trimValue: true,
  freeInput: true,
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'states',
    source: $scope.statesSource.ttAdapter()
  }
});
```

Comment: were you able to come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The [current tagsinput documentation](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#options) indicates that free input "is only possible when using string as tags". This makes me think that using Typeahead + Bloodhound as a source may conflict with the `freeInput` option.

I would try adding a typeahead source as an array of strings instead of using Bloodhound.

```
$('#dailyTagsInput').tagsinput({
  ...
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'states',
    source: $scope.statesSource
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and good thought. I did some further experimenting and found that you can provide an array directly if you use the typeahead option with bootstrap3-typeahead.js (as opposed to typeahead.js). Unfortunately, that still doesn't allow me to enter values that are not included in the array.